# Python: Can this be done in a single list comprehension statement

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What I am trying to do is extracting zeroth element in a list and first element in another list of the given 2 dimensional list.

```
baseball = [[180, 78.4],
            [215, 102.7],
            [210, 98.5],
            [188, 75.2]]

x  =  [ a[0] for a in baseball ] 
y  =  [ a[1] for a in baseball ] 
print x
print y
```

Can this be done in a single list comprehension statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's rectangular (ie. the length of the inner lists is consistent), you can implement the following:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    return [[matrix[j][i] for j in range(len(matrix))] for i in range(len(matrix[0]))]
```

Then, your problem is just a call to transpose (`x, y = transpose(baseball)`).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind tuples:

```
baseball = [[180, 78.4],
            [215, 102.7],
            [210, 98.5],
            [188, 75.2]]


x,y =  zip(*baseball)
```

If you really want lists:

```
x,y = map(list,zip(*baseball))
```

If you had more than two elements in each  and wanted just certain elements like:

```
baseball = [[180, 1, 78.4],
            [215, 2, 102.7],
            [210, 3, 98.5],
            [188, 4, 75.2]]

from operator import itemgetter

x, y = zip(*map(itemgetter(0, 2), baseball))
```

That would give you:

```
 ((180, 215, 210, 188), (78.4, 102.7, 98.5, 75.2))
```

Comment: Standard warning: `zip(*baseball)` won't do the transpose you're looking for if `baseball` is empty.

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly, but was looking for the solution using list-comprehension